# Magento syntax error on line 411

Tags: php, magento, installation, syntax-error

I recently did a manually install of the Magento 2.1.6 running on VPS Apache Account.

I'm unable to run any magento commands from the ssh command line. When I attempt to run 'php bin/magento cron:run I receive the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting 
identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in 
/home/yellowco/public_html/zs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on 
line 411
```

I took a look at the Bootstrap.php file and see the following...

[image]

So it would appear to be something to do with the 'mode' that it's set to . I checked the env.php file and found it set to 'default'. I changed it to developer, but get the same error.

Can you someone help provide some assistance as I really need to get this running.

Comment: Try with this in line no. 411, rename 'class' with 'class_abc' or 'class_xyz'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running PHP >= 5.5.9 from the command line.

You can check your version doing

```
php -v
```

Comment: I have the PHP switcher on my CPanel, which is set to PHP 7.0. However, when I run php -v on the command line I get 5.4.43.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old PHP version. Please check PHP version using command: php -v and see below link in which all requirement are mentioned to run the Magento 2 project.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html